# How can you to interpret a forward slash in a QR code so that the entire string is read using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am developing a web page in which a user can use a barcode scanner to scan a QR code.

I am using the following code to capture the contents of the QR code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var barcode = "";

    $(document).keydown(function (e) { 
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

        barcode = barcode + String.fromCharCode(code);
    });
});
```

There is a forward slash (/) in the QR code that is getting converted to an upside down question mark (¿) and the rest of the code is ignored.

Here is the expected result:

`1111P111FP301X
453530137791
05016/201506
182`

And this is the actual result:

`1111P111FP301Xm453530137791m05016/`

What can I do so that the whole string is read?

Answer (score 0):

To fix your immediate propblem, try using `keypress` event instead of `keydown`. 
There is a certain degree of confusion with regards to how to properly record key strokes. 
Read this helpful article: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var barcode = "";

    $(document).keypress(function (e) { 
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

        barcode = String.fromCharCode(code);

        console.log(barcode + ' : ' + code)
    });


});
```

Works in Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dj1gpnke/1/

Comment: thanks for the reply - your code replaced the upside-down question mark with a forward slash but the rest of the bar code is still getting ignored.

Comment: I don't understand how you read the code. I don't know a lot about QR codes, sorry. Perhaps you can post your input and expected output to clarify.

Comment: I added the expected and actual results to the question.